# ts_backtesting function from TSstudio is not showing in the list of functions in TSstudio package in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have been trying to perform the horse approach for finding the best model to run on the time series data but when I run `ts_backtesting` function, there is a message in console that

> Error in ts_backtesting(x) : could not find function "ts_backtesting"

Can anyone please help me know why I am getting such error and how to avoid that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). `ts_backtesting` function is available in `TSstudio` package. Have you installed and subsequently called the `TSstudio` package in R.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the latest version of the package, didn't find this function anymore
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSstudio/index.html, 
instead, a function called 'train_model' can be used to do a similar thing.